# Set up autologin with SLiM

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, display-manager

I have installed Arch and am having problems with the auto login options within `slim.conf`. I have installed the following X packages:

```
xorg-server
xorg-xinit
xorg-twm, xterm
and for the graphics: xf86-video-fbdev
```

I have also added a user and password, and altered the `sudoers` file to suit. I have changed the following lines:

```
# default_user simone
# auto_login no
```

to:

```
default_user jon
auto_login yes
```

I have managed to get the slim login prompt to appear on boot by editing `/etc/inittab`, but the changes made for bypassing this have not been as successful.

Anybody know what I have missed? Maybe something to do with adding a user to some group?

Comment: could you please add your .xinitrc?

Answer (score 2):

default_user and auto_login looks fine, but how does your login_cmd look?
Does this work for you?

```
login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login ~/.xinitrc %session
```

(with an appropriate ~/.xinitrc in place, that is also "chmod +x"-ed)